# How to do this in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

Is there a directive in chef that will allow me to backup an existing file prior to it being overwritten?

Supposed I have this code.

```
template "myfile"
  source "myfile.erb"
  <more properties>
end
```

The myfile is an existing configuration file and I just need it to be overriden so I used a template.

However, I want the existing file to be backup before it is overwritten by my template.

I can do a backup command like this

```
execute do
    mv  "myfile"  "myfile.old"
end

template "myfile"
  source "myfile.erb"
  <more properties>
end
```

But i was thinking if there is an alternative.

----------------EDIT-----------------------
This looks good but..I am not getting something.. sorry chef newbie here.
According to the documentation, it says..I have to supply this..

backup                     FalseClass, Integer

```
template "myfile"
  source "myfile.erb"
  backup true, 1
end
```

But I am getting this error..

ERROR: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

Sorry, I am new to chef and ruby syntax.  Just picked up chef and learning it on my own.

Comment: `backup` takes either `FalseClass` or an `Integer` as an argument. So call it with `backup 1`. This will keep 1 backup of the file in /var/chef/backup. The default is 5.

Comment: Thanks mate.  I got confused with the documentation, I thought the comma means I have to supply it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you. I use a cookbook because it's a clear way to show you how it works + it avoids directory problems:

first a directory in which I store my cookbooks:

```
$ mkdir cookbooks
```

Now I'm going to create my cookbook with the name create-backup

```
$ chef generate cookbook cookbooks/create-backup
```

I will also create a template inside my cookbook which will be the file I'll backup

```
$ chef generate template cookbooks/create-backup myfile-tobackup.txt
```

This is what's inside my cookbook:

```
tree cookbooks/create-backup/
$ cookbooks/create-backup/
|-- Berksfile
|-- chefignore
|-- metadata.rb
|-- README.md
|-- recipes
|   `-- default.rb
|-- spec
|   |-- spec_helper.rb
|   `-- unit
|       `-- recipes
|           `-- default_spec.rb
|-- templates
|   |-- default
|   `-- myfile-tobackup.txt.erb
`-- test
    `-- smoke
        `-- default
            `-- default_test.rb
```

Only the recipes and the templates are important for your case.
I'll put some input in the `myfile-tobackup.txt.erb`

```
$ vi cookbooks/create-backup/templates/myfile-tobackup.txt.erb
Content:
this is version 1
```

Now I'm editing the `default.rb` in the recipes (this file will be executed if you run the cookbook).

```
$ vi cookbooks/create-backup/recipes/default.rb
```

And the content:

```
template '/tmp/backup' do
   source 'myfile-tobackup.txt.erb'
   backup 3
end
```

This means I will create a file with the name backup in `/tmp` from the source `myfile-tobackup.txt` and I will create a max of 3 backups.

Now I can execute my cookbook by running the recipe of my cookbook:

```
$ chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[create-backup]'
```

I'll check:

```
$ cat /tmp/backup
this is version 1
```

Now I can edit the content of my template `myfile-tobackup.txt.erb` and set the version to 2. When I rerun the cookbook the `/tmp/backup` will contain "this is version 2" but your old `/tmp/backup` is backuped in `/var/chef/backup` (it will keep 3 files).

Comment: Thanks mate for such detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Chef handles this automatically and internally. By default we keep 5 versions of every template file, which you can customize via the [`backup` property](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html#properties). These end up under `/var/chef/backups` usually.

The `backup` property takes either `false` to disable backups, or an integer value to set the number of backups to keep. You can not pass it `true`.

Comment: I think this looks promising. But can you help me with my problem above. I know this is something basic.  I just picked up chef so hopefully you would be patient on me.

Comment: Thanks again mate.  I figured it out from the comments.